# struts2 junit 2.3.12 plugin - unable to write successful test in struts2 junit4

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, struts2, junit4, struts2-junit-plugin

I'm using struts2 junit 2.3.12 plugin.

1. If I run test directly, then I get :

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext`

so I include

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

in my POM, after which I get :

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/ServletException
```

so, I remove the above dependency and add :

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

after which I get

```
SEVERE:   [53:22.549] Dispatcher initialization failed
```

Below is my test :

```
public class TestAction extends StrutsTestCase {

    @Test
    public void testRegister() throws Exception {
        ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy("/gotoregister");
        assertNotNull(proxy);

        proxy = getActionProxy("/registeraction");
        UserAction action = (UserAction) proxy.getAction();
        assertNotNull(action);
        request.setParameter("usernameexists", "true");
        request.setParameter("emailexists", "false");
        request.setParameter("basicinfo.firstname", "fname");
        request.setParameter("basicinfo.lastname", "lname");
        request.setParameter("user.username", "test");
        request.setParameter("user.email", "nitin.cool4urchat@gmail.com");
        request.setParameter("user.passwd", "nn");
        request.setParameter("repasswd", "nn");
        request.setParameter("gender", "nn");
        request.setParameter("basicinfo.country", "India");
        String result = action.execute();
        assertEquals("input", result);
        System.out.println(action.getActionErrors());
        System.out.println(action.getActionMessages());
    }
}
```

Please help me in writing a successful test.

[EDIT] - I thought I should add my complete POM, so below is maximum part of the POM :

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net2</id>
            <name>Repository hosting the jee6 artifacts</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.8-beta4</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>-->

<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>${struts.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-junit-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.ga</version>
        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbc-stdext</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1B</version>
        </dependency>-->

<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmock-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <version>3.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
<!--            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.14</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <webDefaultXml>src/main/resources/webdefault.xml</webDefaultXml>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector">
                            <port>8080</port>
                        </connector>
                    </connectors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1-beta-1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>GoldenTraderMaven</finalName>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>endorsed</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>sun.boot.class.path</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                             javaee6 contains upgrades of APIs contained within the JDK itself.
                                 As such these need to be placed on the bootclasspath, rather than classpath of the
                                 compiler.
                                 If you don't make use of these new updated API, you can delete the profile.
                                 On non-SUN jdk, you will need to create a similar profile for your jdk, with the similar property as sun.boot.class.path in Sun's JDK.
                            <compilerArguments>
                                <bootclasspath>${settings.localRepository}/javax/javaee-endorsed-api/6.0/javaee-endorsed-api-6.0.jar${path.separator}${sun.boot.class.path}</bootclasspath>
                            </compilerArguments>
                        </configuration>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>Tomcat60</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
        <struts.version>2.3.12</struts.version>
        <hibernate.version>3.6.10.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Try with `javax.servlet:servlet-api` dependency.

Comment: I tried that, after which I got `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext` so I included jsp-api too in my POM and then it seems to execute test fine. Thank you so much for urgent response.

Comment: Yep, forgot about jsp-api. Added my comment as an answer. You can accept it if it helped you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add dependencies of `javax.servlet:servlet-api` and `javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api` to your project pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```